# How to convert Date value into Age

Tags: python, date

I am having a dataset which contains date of birth values column. I have to convert those date of births into age.

01-01-84

31-07-85

24-08-85

30-12-93

09-12-77

Name: DOB, dtype: object

How should I convert this DOB column into Age

Comment: Subtract the date of birth in the column from today's date

Answer (score 0):

```
a = datetime.datetime.now()   # Current datetime
b = datetime.datetime.strptime("01 01 84", "%d %m %y")  # if your data type is string you can convert it with strptime to datetime object
age = a.year - b.year  # here you calculate the age
print(age)  # output 35
```

Comment: is datetime.datetime.now() is from datetime package right?

Comment: How should I pass the whole column in strptime() function ?

Comment: You should show the data strucutre you are using. For example if you are using pandas you can easily grab it by colomn name. Show your code or your data structure type